# How to create an Array or ArrayList of objects in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have custom object MyClass and I need to create 3 instances of it.

Instead of doing something dumb like:

```
MyClass instance1 = new MyClass();
MyClass instance2 = new MyClass();
MyClass instance3 = new MyClass();
```

Shouldnt I be able to do something like this:

```
MyClass[] instances = new MyClass();

instances[0].somemethod;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyClass[] instances = new MyClass[3];

for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
   instances[i] = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 7):

Do it inside a loop:

```
MyClass[] instances=new MyClass[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   instances[i]= new MyClass(); 
}
```

Or create the array directly:

```
MyClass[] instances= new MyClass[]{new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass()};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
MyClass[] instances = new MyClass[num];
for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
  instances[i]=new MyClass();
}
```

or

```
MyClass[] instances = new MyClass[]{ new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass()};
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using LINQ?

```
MyClass[] instances = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 3).Select(i => new MyClass()).ToArray();
```

Performance considerations are left as an exercise for the reader.  ;-)

Comment: That's almost exactly what I had!  Too late to see how many seconds apart our answers were.

Comment: I think you actually beat me by a hair!

Comment: +1 concise and very readable to anyone who uses "functional .NET"

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
MyClass[] instances Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => new MyClass()).ToArray();
```

The starting value `0` doesn't matter, we just want some IEnumerable with 3 elements.  Alternatively `Enumerable.Repeat` also works, again just ignoring the first argument.

Comment: @Timwi: errmm, what? The code is identical to the versions implementing the for loop by hand, I don't find it any more or less clever. Perhaps readability can be improved by adding line-breaks after the linq methods.

Comment: I am not sure if its clever, but I don't think its unreadable.. however Bernard's question is what I was looking for.